# Scale surface size using direct3d

Tags: c++, directx, direct3d

I making a program that takes screenshots, i use GetFrontBufferData and D3DXSaveSurfaceToFile. All screenshots saving in original monitor resolution. I need be able to save them in different resolutions. How i can do this?

```
ZeroMemory(&d3dpp, sizeof(D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS));

    d3dpp.Windowed = TRUE;
    d3dpp.Flags = D3DPRESENTFLAG_LOCKABLE_BACKBUFFER;
    d3dpp.BackBufferFormat = ddm.Format;
    d3dpp.BackBufferHeight = nDisplayHeight = gScreenRect.bottom = ddm.Height;
    d3dpp.BackBufferWidth = nDisplayWidth = gScreenRect.right = ddm.Width;
    d3dpp.MultiSampleType = D3DMULTISAMPLE_NONE;
    d3dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
    d3dpp.hDeviceWindow = hWnd;
    d3dpp.PresentationInterval = D3DPRESENT_INTERVAL_DEFAULT;
    d3dpp.FullScreen_RefreshRateInHz = D3DPRESENT_RATE_DEFAULT;

    g_pD3D->CreateDevice(i, D3DDEVTYPE_REF, hWnd, D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING, &d3dpp, &g_pd3dDevice);
    //g_pd3dDevice->GetRenderTarget(0, &g_pSurface);
    g_pd3dDevice->CreateOffscreenPlainSurface(ddm.Width, ddm.Height, D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8, D3DPOOL_SYSTEMMEM, &g_pSurface, NULL);
    SetCursor(LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_WAIT));
    g_pd3dDevice->GetFrontBufferData(0, g_pSurface);

    D3DXSaveSurfaceToFile(argv[0], D3DXIFF_BMP, g_pSurface, NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: Use [WIC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719902.aspx) to resize the output image.

Comment: @CodeAngry i' m really couldn't find some good examples how to use it with D3D. Do i need to save surface to image first, or i can save it to memory, and then load it using WIC.

Comment: You should take a look at the source for [DirectXTex](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248926) which makes heavy use of WIC.

Comment: @NickEatMore Do what's easier for you. I think saving to file, loading resizing and saving again is. Even if not most efficient. It can be done all in memory and you'll find loads of WIC examples online `CreateBitmapFromMemory(...)`. --- I don't really know how to use D3D output directly... But look at DxTex as CW says.